# Errors when running apt after 23.04 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, dkms

I apologise in advance; I'm not a proficient Linux user.

I get errors whenever I try to do anything with apt. This was after upgrading to 23.04 from 18.04 through 20.04, 22.04, and 22.10 using the GUI.

It looks like the dkms build was skipped or something and I have (many) old modules. But I'm unsure what to remove (or how to) and what to keep. I'm running `6.2.0-27-generic` with `6.2.0-26-generic` as a recovery. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is what I get if I run `apt-get autoremove`. I'm removing a ton of `Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)` messages from the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 1 not to upgrade.
6 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-6.2.0-27-generic (6.2.0-27.28) ...
Setting up linux-headers-6.2.0-27-generic (6.2.0-27.28) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.2.0-27-generic
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/etc/dkms/framework.conf)
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j8 KERNELRELEASE=6.2.0-27-generic BUILD_KERNEL=dummy KSRC=/lib/modules/6.2.0-27-generic/build...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/e1000e-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.2.0-27-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.2.0-27-generic/x86_64 succeeded for v4l2loopback v4l2loopback v4l2loopback virtualbox virtualbox
dkms autoinstall on 6.2.0-27-generic/x86_64 failed for e1000e(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.2.0-27-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-headers-6.2.0-27-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic:
 linux-headers-generic depends on linux-headers-6.2.0-27-generic; however:
  Package linux-headers-6.2.0-27-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic (6.2.0-26.26) ...
Setting up linux-headers-6.2.0-26-generic (6.2.0-26.26) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.2.0-26-generic
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/etc/dkms/framework.conf)
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j8 KERNELRELEASE=6.2.0-26-generic BUILD_KERNEL=dummy KSRC=/lib/modules/6.2.0-26-generic/build...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/e1000e-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.2.0-26-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.2.0-26-generic/x86_64 succeeded for v4l2loopback v4l2loopback v4l2loopback virtualbox virtualbox
dkms autoinstall on 6.2.0-26-generic/x86_64 failed for e1000e(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.2.0-26-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-headers-6.2.0-26-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-headers-generic (= 6.2.0.27.27); however:
  Package linux-headers-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Processing triggers for linux-image-6.2.0-27-generic (6.2.0-27.28) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.2.0-27-generic
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/etc/dkms/framework.conf)
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j8 KERNELRELEASE=6.2.0-27-generic BUILD_KERNEL=dummy KSRC=/lib/modules/6.2.0-27-generic/build...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/e1000e-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.2.0-27-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.2.0-27-generic/x86_64 succeeded for v4l2loopback v4l2loopback v4l2loopback virtualbox virtualbox
dkms autoinstall on 6.2.0-27-generic/x86_64 failed for e1000e(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.2.0-27-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.2.0-27-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Processing triggers for linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic (6.2.0-26.26) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.2.0-26-generic
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/etc/dkms/framework.conf)
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/source/dkms.conf)

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j8 KERNELRELEASE=6.2.0-26-generic BUILD_KERNEL=dummy KSRC=/lib/modules/6.2.0-26-generic/build...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/e1000e-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.2.0-26-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/e1000e/3.4.2.4/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.2.0-26-generic/x86_64 succeeded for v4l2loopback v4l2loopback v4l2loopback virtualbox virtualbox
dkms autoinstall on 6.2.0-26-generic/x86_64 failed for e1000e(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-6.2.0-27-generic
 linux-headers-generic
 linux-headers-6.2.0-26-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-image-6.2.0-27-generic
 linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here's dkms status:

```
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-1094-oem, x86_64: installed
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-1096-oem, x86_64: installed
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-1097-oem, x86_64: installed
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-1099-oem, x86_64: installed
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-1100-oem, x86_64: installed
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-1101-oem, x86_64: installed
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-1102-oem, x86_64: installed
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-1103-oem, x86_64: installed
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-156-generic, x86_64: installed
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-158-generic, x86_64: installed
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-159-generic, x86_64: installed
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-161-generic, x86_64: installed
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-162-generic, x86_64: installed
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-163-generic, x86_64: installed
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-166-generic, x86_64: installed
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-167-generic, x86_64: installed
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-169-generic, x86_64: installed
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-171-generic, x86_64: installed
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-173-generic, x86_64: installed
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-175-generic, x86_64: installed
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-176-generic, x86_64: installed
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-177-generic, x86_64: installed
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-180-generic, x86_64: installed
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-184-generic, x86_64: installed
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-187-generic, x86_64: installed
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-188-generic, x86_64: installed
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-189-generic, x86_64: installed
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-191-generic, x86_64: installed
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-192-generic, x86_64: installed
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-193-generic, x86_64: installed
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-194-generic, x86_64: installed
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-196-generic, x86_64: installed
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-197-generic, x86_64: installed
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-200-generic, x86_64: installed
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-201-generic, x86_64: installed
e1000e/3.4.2.4, 4.15.0-202-generic, x86_64: installed
v4l2loopback/0.12.7, 5.19.0-46-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
v4l2loopback/0.12.7, 6.2.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
v4l2loopback/0.12.7, 6.2.0-27-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
virtualbox/7.0.6, 6.2.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox/7.0.6, 6.2.0-27-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: I don't know if this fixed it, but I found out the `e1000e` module is installed via the apt package `e1000e-dkms`. I don't know if I needed it, but I decided to remove it anyway since the versions were older. I don't get the error anymore, which may be good.

Comment: Please remove all the old kernel packages too.

Comment: @nobody is there a way to list all the old kernel packages?

Comment: `sudo apt autoremove -- purge`

Comment: @nobody ah thanks! I did run that already!